# Firebug debugging JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging

Is there a way I can attach the debugger to an event?

I have a checkbox input element in my DOM and when it's clicked, I'd like the debugger to break so I can step through what's happening. I've added `onclick="debugger;` ...", but Firebug doesn't break.

Comment: I suggest to take a look to Eventbug (http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug).

I don't know if you can do what you request using Eventbug, but certanly has lots of options to view event handlers, log events in the console...

Answer (score 2):

Create an onclick handler for the checkbox, and add a breakpoint to that handler.  For example (jQuery):

```
$('input#mycheckbox').click(function() {
    console.log("click checkbox");
});
```

In firebug you can add a breakpoint to the `console.log` line.

Answer (score 1):

Find the javascript line in firebug and set a breakpoint. You should'nt need to modify your Javascript at all.

Check out this page, specifically the "Pause execution on any line" section to see what this looks like visually.

Comment: Well that's the thing--there is no JavaScript line.

Comment: Then set a breakpoint on the first line of the event handler.